# Plain text attachment ends up in base64

Tags: android, email, android-intent, base64, email-attachments

From my Android app, I'm trying to allow the user to send an email with an atachment. The attachment is a plain text file. I want the user to be able to select only email-apps to send this email.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,  "Some awesome email");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check out the attachment!");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath()));
listActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email with...");
```

Only email apps are shown, so far so good. When I use gmail to send the email, the email arrives as it should, atachment and all.

BUT, when I use k9 mail to send the email, the attachment ends up being encoded in base64. So basically, it's unreadable.

When I use

```
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

the attachment arrives fine (in plain text), but the choose-app-dialog contains non-email apps.

How can I get the best of both worlds? Only email apps in the choose-app-dialog and text file attachments that arrive in plain text no matter which email client is used?

Answer (score 1):

`Intent.createChooser()` gives you back a regular `Intent`. Just modify the `Intent` that you get back. Something like this:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,  "Some awesome email");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check out the attachment!");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath()));
Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email with...");
intent.setType("text/plain");
listActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I get an ActivityNotFoundException if I try this ("No activity found to handle Intent")